# Testing if $X_1$ has an influence of $Y$

Tags: statistics, regression

> > Consider you have the suspicion that $Y$ is influenced by two attributes $X_1$ and $X_2$:
> >     $$
> > Y=\theta_0+\theta_1X_1+\theta_2X_2+\theta_3 X_1X_2+U
> > $$
> >     The following data are given. Test on a level of $\alpha=0.05$ if $X_1$ has an influence on $Y$.
> >     $$
> > \begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}\\
> > \hline
> > x_1 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 7 & 13 & 10\\
> > x_2 & 148 & 155 & 138 & 142 & 177 & 159 & 158 & 143 & 153 & 162\\
> > y & 296 & 303 & 285 & 288 &  324 & 304 & 305 & 291 & 300 & 310\\
> > \hline
> > \end{array}
> > $$
> >     $$
> > \begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}\\
> > \hline
> > x_1 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 11 & 6 & 9 & 7 & 10\\
> > x_2 & 158 & 139 & 153 & 144 & 157 & 167 & 139 & 142 & 155 & 144\\
> > y & 307 & 287 & 300 & 292 & 305 & 315 & 286 & 187 & 304 & 290\\
> > \hline
> > \end{array}
> > $$

I do not know how to test this, because of the mixted term $\theta_3 X_1X_2$. If this term would not be there, the testhypothesis would be
$$
H_0: \theta_1=0\text{ vs. }H_1: \theta_1\neq 0.
$$
But because of the mixted term I do not know how to test.

**Update**

My only idea is that the test problem might be formulated as the following:

$H_0: \theta_1=\theta_3=0$ vs. $H_1: \theta_i\neq 0$ for at least one $i=1,3$

But I do not know if I have to test this as ONE test (which test statistic?) or as TWO separated test problems (which level each?)

$H_0^1: \theta_1=0$ vs. $H_1^1: \theta_1\neq 0$ (test 1)

$H_0^2: \theta_3=0$ vs. $H_1^2: \theta_3\neq 0$ (test 2)

and then to refuse $H_0$ if at least one of both tests shows that $H_0^i, i=1,2$ has to be refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already wrote, the test problem is
$$
H_0: \theta_1=\theta_3=0\text{  vs.  }H_1: \theta_i\neq 0\text{  for at least one  }i=1,3.
$$
But you should not test this in two separated t-tests! Instead you can write this test problem with a suitable restriction matrix $R$, getting
$$
H_0: R\theta=0\text{  vs.  }H_1: R\theta\neq 0
$$
and use a $F$-test.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform linear regression including an interaction term among the independent variables.  This can be easily obtained using common statistical softwares.

Comment: I know how to make a linear regression... but not with an interaction term. How can I do so?

Comment: The software should have an "interaction" command. Alternatively, you can create an additional independent variable equal to the product of the two independent variables for which you want to test the interaction.

Comment: You mean $X_3=x_1X_2$? And then?

Comment: Yes. Then you can insert this third variable into the model and test the three variables.

Comment: So the test problem then is $H_0: \theta_1=\theta_3=0$ vs. $H_1: \theta_i\neq 0$ for at least one $i=1,3$? If yes: How to test that?

Comment: So if I set $X_3:=X_1\cdot X_2$ and make linear regression I get that $Y=285.05-34.93X_1+0.15X_2+0.22X_3$. But that's not the answert of the question?!

Comment: In the opening question you stated that you want to test on a level of $\alpha=0.05$ whether $X_1$ has an influence on $Y$. This is the hypothesis. Look at significance of $\theta_1$ after running the three-variable regression.

Comment: I used R. It says to me: $Y=288.05-34.93X_1+0.15X_2+0.22X_3$, p-value $0.03779$. So $p<0.05$ and the hypothesis can be refused. But nonetheless it is not clear to me what exactly the nullhypothesis is (it is just that $\theta_1=0$?) and what role the interaction term $\theta_3X_1X_2$ does play.

Comment: Look at the significance of the single parameters, not only at that of the overall model. Is $\theta_1$ significant?

Comment: Do you mean the t-value for $\theta_1$? It is -1.27.

Comment: If you have only the t value, you must check the corresponding p value for the appropriate degrees of freedom. You can convert t in p using one of the various online tools

Comment: Ok, the t-value for $\theta_1$ is -1.24, the p-value is $0.22$. So the Nullhypothesis $\theta_1=0$ cannot be rejected. What do I have to do now?

Comment: Check significance of the other two variables of the model.

Comment: Both are not significant.

Comment: So when I have multiple linear regression with interaction terms I have to look if the single terms are significant and the interaction term is significant?

Comment: In this case, since $\theta_1$ and $\theta3$ are not significant, you conclude that the variable $X_1$ has no influence on $Y$, either as main effect or as interaction.

Comment: Ok, coool. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, was it all ok with your analysis?